# Simplifying $\frac{x^4(y-z)+y^4(z-x)+z^4(x-y)}{(y+z)^2+(z+x)^2+(x+y)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help to simplify this expression.

$$\frac{x^4(y-z)+y^4(z-x)+z^4(x-y)}{(y+z)^2+(z+x)^2+(x+y)^2}$$

I only know to start, I extracted the $(x-y)$ from top one, and then I don't know what's next. Extracting $(x-y)$ from the numerator:

$$(x^4y - y^4x) - (zy^4-zx^4)+z^4(x-y)$$
$$ = xy(x^3-y^3)- z(x^4-y^4)+z^4(x-y)$$
$$ = xy(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)-z(x-y)(x+y)(x^2+y^2)+z^4(x-y)$$
$$ = (x-y)\left[ xy(x^2+xy+y^2) - z(x+y)(x^2+y^2) +z^4 \right]$$
$$ = (x-y)(x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3-zx^3-zy^3+z^4-zxy^2-zx^2y)$$

Comment: @LukaSimic: If you can extract $(x-y)$ from the numerator, then the *symmetry* of the expression suggests that you can do more.

Comment: I know that i can do more but i dont know which parts to but together there are so many left in brackets after i extract (x-y)

Comment: I would echo @Blue's comment and also suggest that if you "do more" you may find more efficient ways of simplifying the numerator.

Comment: Try multiplying the denominator by $(x-y)^3+(z-x)^3+(y-z)^3$

Comment: @LukaSimic: If you show the work you've done, then we'll be better able to advise you about how to continue. (See [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/409) for tips on formatting mathematical expressions.)

Comment: @Blue: thank You sooo much Blue i am new here and English isnt my first language so i am still learning how to use it

Comment: @Blue: i posted picture of what i have done can you take a look

Comment: @LukaSimic Welcome to MSE! Usually using pictures is difficult unless something needs to be pictured. I've transcribed your picture into MathJax; in the future, you should use that rather than uploading a picture. Feel free to correct my transcription if something is incorrectly transcribed.

Comment: @EricSnyder : Thank you soo much, i tried to look at tutorial now but i cant do it immediatly in 2-3 days i will learn it , sorry

Comment: For this purpose, it's likely enough to go and look at what I did (using the edit button); the rest of this problem won't use anything more complex than that. :)

Comment: @EricSnyder :)) do you know maybe how should i solve it

Comment: Do you understand Blue and Mark's hint?  If you understand it, then you already know two more factors.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I dont understand how should i factor it out can you give me more hint, it would helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

I like Pavel's answer, but here's a slightly different way.

Starting with $(x-y)(x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3−zx^3−zy^3+z^4−zxy^2−zx^2y)$, rearrange the longer expression to:

$$(x^3y-zx^3) + (xy^3-zxy^2) + (x^2y^2 - zx^2y) + (z^4 - zy^3)$$
$$ = (y-z)(x^3 + xy^2 + x^2y) - z(z^3-y^3)$$
$$ = (y-z)(x^2y + xy^2 + x^2y -z(y^2+yz+z^2)) $$

Giving us $(x-y)(y-z)(x^2y+xy^2+x^2y-y^2z-yz^2-z^3)$ as the numerator. Again, rearrange the new long expression as:

$$(xy^2-zy^2) + (x^3-z^3) + (x^2y-yz^2)$$
$$ = (x-z)y^2 + (x-z)(x^2+xz+z^2)+y(x-z)(x+z)$$

And we can factor out the $(x-z)$. This gives the numerator as:

$$(x-y)(y-z)(x-z)(x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz)$$

But if we expand the denominator, we get:

$$x^2+2xy+y^2 + x^2+2xz+z^2 + y^2+2yz+z^2 = 2(x^2+y^2+x^2+xy+xz+yz)$$

And we recognize that as having the same expression in parentheses as the last expression in the numerator! So when we divide we get:

$$\frac{(x-y)(y-z)(x-z)}{2} = - \frac{(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)}{2}$$

Which is the same as Pavel's answer. Taking the negative out just makes the numerator look symmetrical. If you expand the numerator, you get another symmetrical expression:

$$\frac12 \big(xy(x-y) + yz(y-z) + zx(z-x) \big)$$

which is longer but, I think, just a bit nicer-looking.

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing a more systematic way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

The nominator is a degree 5 polynomial and the denominator degree 2 polynomial, so if the fraction should simplify into a polynomial, it would have to be of degree 3, symmetric, and with the same number of positive and negative terms. My first guess is to consider the symmetric polynomial
$$
  (x-y)(y-z)(z-x) 
= y (z^2-x^2) + z (x^2-y^2) + x (y^2-z^2). 
$$
Let's try when we multiply it by the denominator of the fraction:
\begin{align}
  &\frac 1 2((x-y)(y-z)(z-x) 
  \Big((y+z)^2 + (z+x)^2 + (x+y)^2\Big) \\
&= \Big(y (z^2-x^2) + z (x^2-y^2) + x (y^2-z^2)\Big) \Big(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + xy + yz + zx\Big)\\ 
&= \Big(y (z^2-x^2) + \ldots \Big) \Big(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + xy + yz + zx\Big)\\ 
&= \Big(y (z^2-x^2) + \ldots\Big) \Big(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \Big) \quad \color{red}{=: A}\\
& \ + \Big(y (z^2-x^2) + \ldots\Big) \Big(xy + yz + zx\Big)  \quad \color{red}{=: B}, 
\end{align}
where I use the notation $(\it \text{expression}+\ldots)$ to represent the cyclical completion of the expression $x\to y \to z (\to x)$. For example $(xy+\ldots)$ represents the expression $xy + yz + zx$, which could equivalently be represented by $(yz+\ldots)$ or $(yz+\ldots)$.

---

Taking into account that the expression $\big(x^2 + y^2 + z^2\big)$ is symmetric, we can write
\begin{align}
A &= \Big( y (z^2-x^2) \big(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \big) + \ldots \Big) \\
&=\Big( y \big(z^2x^2- x^4 + z^2 y^2 -x^2 y^2 + z^4 - x^2 z^2\big) + \ldots  \Big) \\
&= \Big(2y (z^2 y^2 -x^2 y^2 + z^4-x^4) + \ldots  \Big) \\
&= \Big(y^3 z^2 - x^2 y^3 + \ldots  \Big) + 2\Big(y(z^4-x^4) + \ldots  \Big) \\
&= \Big(x^3 y^2 - x^2 y^3 +\ldots \Big)
 -\Big(x^4(y-z) + y^4(z-x) + z^4 (x-y) \Big),
\end{align}
where in the last line we took into the fact that the cyclical term $(y^3z^2+\ldots) = (x^3y^2+\ldots)$.

---

Taking into account that the expression $\big(xy + yz + zx\big)$ is symmetric, we can write
\begin{align}
B &= \Big(y (z^2-x^2) \big(xy + yz + zx\big) + \ldots \Big) \\
&\Big(
xy^2z^2 - x^3 y^2 + y^2 z^3 - x^2 y^2 z + xyz^3 - x^3 y z + \ldots \Big) \\
&=xyz \Big(yz - xy + z^2 - x^2 + \ldots \Big)+
 \Big(- x^3 y^2 + y^2 z^3 +  \ldots \Big) \\
&= \Big(- x^3 y^2 + y^2 z^3 +  \ldots \Big) \\
&= \Big(- x^3 y^2 + x^2 y^3 +  \ldots \Big) 
\end{align}

---

We conclude that
$A + B = -\Big(x^4(y-z) + y^4(z-x) + z^4 (x-y) \Big),$
and so
$$
\frac{x^4(y-z) + y^4(z-x) + z^4 (x-y)}
{(y+z)^2 + (z+x)^2 + (x+y)^2} =
  - \frac 1 2 (x-y)(y-z)(z-x).
$$

Comment: Thank you sooo much bro , you dont know how much you helped me <3

Comment: You are welcome, it was fun to play with it. I hope that the manipulations are understandable, I'm too tired now to add better comments there.